# Excel Adds "@" Sign Into Formula Created by XLSXWriter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsxwriter

In XLSXWriter, I'm using the following code to add a formula to a workbook:

```
worksheet.write_formula(row, col, '=MAX(IF(AL3:AL7<=$AI$8,AL3:AL7))')
```

When I open the workbook in Excel, it has an "@" sign inserted into it, and throws a "#VALUE!" error.

```
=MAX(IF(@AL3:AL7<=$AI$8,AL3:AL7))
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I had to write the formula using `write_array_formula` instead of `write_formula`.